# Sending an object method as a response NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

my requirements are to send an object method as a response using express. This is so that I can create dynamic onClick js code in front-end.

```
const data = {
  message: "Hi",
  click: () => {
    console.log("Hello world");
  }
};
res.send(data);
```

I tried to send it, but the method won't send. The log for the above sample code in front-end JS is as below.

```
{message: "Hi"}
```

My workaround was to send the whole function as a string and then use **Function Constructor** to parse the string. It worked, but I read other forum entries where it said it is very bad practice to parse a string as a function.

Kindly suggest the ways through which I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have two choices:

1. Use the `Function` constructor as you are. It's fine ***if*** you can trust who you're getting the string from that you're converting into code. What you shouldn't do is use it when you don't need to convert a string to a function (e.g., there's a better way), or with a string from a source you can't trust.
2. Don't send dynamic handlers at all. Instead, have a set of standard handlers in a script that you include in your page:

   ```
   const handlers = {
       sayHi() {
           alert("Hello world");
       },
       doSomething() {
           // ...
       },
       doSomethingElse() {
           // ...
       }
   };
   ```

   and send back the name of a handler (`"sayHi"`, `"doSomething"`, `"doSomethingElse"`) rather than the code of the handler. Then you use the handler via `handlers[name]`.